Could the Elo rating system (used in chess, etc.) be used for language proficiency?
I used to be a bit of a chess player, where we rank chess proficiency using the Elo rating system (or the Glicko rating system).  When you "win" your rating goes up, and when you "lose" your rating goes down; how much it goes up/down by is determined by the difficulty of your opponent.  This is often adapted to "chess puzzles" where both players and puzzles have Elo ratings.
It seems like you could use a comparable system for language proficiency.  Give the student a language-related problem: if they get the answer right, their rating goes up, and if they get it wrong, their rating goes down.
In fact, it seems like you could take the same puzzle system used at LiChess.com, and replace it with language learning puzzles instead of chess puzzles.
Question: Could the Elo rating system (used in chess, etc.) be used for language proficiency?
I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing that makes this theoretically impossible, or if it's already been implemented in some app for some language.

Arpad Elo designed the rating system for relative rankings in competitions. Since chess is not the only type of competition, Elo ratings have found their use in various sports and competitive games.
Elo is based on the odds that one player wins against another based on their rating difference. Discussions about the inflation in chess ratings go back at least 30 years; the first article presenting mathematical arguments that I read was published in Europe Échecs around 1990, i.e. before Jeff Sonas started started writing about improvements to the Elo rating system.
I see two big issues with using language-related problems for a language-proficiency rating.

Glicko ratings on LiChess are inflated compared to FIDE ratings. See for example How do FIDE rated players perform on lichess?. So what would those language-related problems really be measuring? In other words, how would the ratings correlated with real-world proficiency? And if you set up different systems for different languages, what would it mean if the same person had rating X in one language and rating Y in another language, even though other, more thorough, tests say she is at CEFR level C1?
Language proficiency and language fluency aren't really competitive. Communication is very often collaborative (you say or write something and the other party often asks a follow-up question, a clarification, etc. or confirms that they understood what you meant). You can, of course, test grammar and vocabulary, but you'll need to make sure that the system can deal with multiple correct answers (unlike some chess puzzle systems). In addition, correct grammar and vocabulary are only a part of language proficiency. It is perfectly possible to get by in the real world with only partially correct grammar and vocabulary, as many non-native speakers prove on a daily basis.

